# Optimizing 'nested for loop' over MLMultiArray in Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, numpy, coreml, mlmodel

I have a nested for loop (from [here](https://github.com/tucan9389/PoseEstimation-CoreML/blob/master/PoseEstimation-CoreML/Common/HeatmapPostProcessor.swift#L34))

`heatmaps` is an MLMultiArray at shape of (14, 50, 60).
This code iterates 14 sub-arrays of shape (50,60), and finding the maximum for each value.

This is the code:

```c
for k in 0..<keypoint_number {
        for i in 0..<heatmap_w {
            for j in 0..<heatmap_h {
                let index = k*(heatmap_w*heatmap_h) + i*(heatmap_h) + j
                let confidence = heatmaps[index].doubleValue
                guard confidence > 0 else { continue }
                if n_kpoints[k] == nil ||
                    (n_kpoints[k] != nil && n_kpoints[k]!.maxConfidence < confidence) {
                    n_kpoints[k] = PredictedPoint(maxPoint: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(j), y: CGFloat(i)), maxConfidence: confidence)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Equivalent python code:

```py
for p_ind in range(n_keypoints):
    heat = heatmaps[0, p_ind, :, :]
    ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(heat), heat.shape)
```

The Swift function takes around ~36ms with iPhone 12 mini, and ~58ms with iPhone 11 Pro Max.
I want to optimize it and reduce it's runtime.

How can I do it?

Will it help if I write the code in Objective-C? How can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Accelerate framework has an optimized argmax function. You can also find this in CoreMLHelpers on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find this argmax function? It sounds exactly what I need.
I don't see it here: https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers/tree/master/CoreMLHelpers.
I see "argmax" for Array, but not for MLMultiArray.
In addition, the access to the MLMultiArray is by *index*, even if I had argmax function, how do I use it in the given code? 
Maybe I can convert it to (14,50,60) array first?

Comment: You need to pass in the pointer to the MLMultiArray's contents. In your case, since the array is (14, 50, 60) you also need to pass in a stride of 50 * 60.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am sorry, I don't understand the proposed solution for the question. If you post an answer and it will work - I will gladly accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps in your case it would be easiest to add the argmax operation into the model itself. You can see an example here, from my book: https://github.com/hollance/coreml-survival-guide/blob/4dfcbb97c065726a3da240c55d90b2075959801d/Scripts/deeplab.py#L94-L109

Comment: I am trying to add it in an additional Keras Lambda layer. This is not a single argmax, but argmax for each one of the 14 heatmaps of size (50,60). As I understand in your example is a single argmax. 
Thanks

Comment: In the example it's an argmax over the 14 channels. So for every pixel in the 50x60 heatmap it tells you which one of the 14 classes has the highest probability.